# Reject null, if and only if q-value is no more than the FDR threshold?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

In multiple comparisons, suppose we have calculated $q$-values. Is it a $q$-value for each test, or a $q$-value for all the multiple comparisons?

Given a false discovery rate (FDR) threshold on FDR, are $q$-values used to determine whether to accept or reject each null? For an individual test, is it rejected **if and only if** its $q$-value is no less than the FDR threshold? Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to be a little more specific about which FDR you mean, as there are several. One typical False Discovery Rate procedure, due to [Benjamini and Hochberg](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346101), helps you find an FDR threshold without directly computing $q$ values. it works like this:

1. Choose an overall $\alpha$ value for the false discovery/false positive rate.
2. Perform all $m$ individual hypothesis tests ($H_1 \ldots H_m)$, whatever they may be, to produce a list of $p$-values.
3. Sort the $p$-values, so that $P_{(1)}$ is the smallest and $P_{(m)}$ is the largest. Rearrange the $H$s so the indices match.
4. Step up from $k=0$ to $k=m$ through your data to find the largest $k$ such that $P_{(k)} \le \frac{k}{m \cdot c(m)}\alpha$. The $c(m)$ is a correction factor, due to [Benjamini and Yekutieli](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-29/issue-4/The-control-of-the-false-discovery-rate-in-multiple-testing/10.1214/aos/1013699998.full), that adjusts for various kinds of dependence/correlation between the tests.
5. The null hypotheses $H_1 \ldots H_k$ (if any) can be rejected; you fail to reject the remaining null hypothesis (if any).

Note that you don't actually get a $q$ value anywhere in this procedure; it just identifies hypotheses, based on their $p$-values, that you can reject. If you had slightly different data, you might have rejected a null based on a slightly larger $p$ value too.  However, you can compute an mean $\alpha$ for your all $m$ tests (for positive dependence, where $c(m)=1$, it's $\bar{\alpha}=\frac{m+1}{2m} \alpha$). Some people also abuse notation slightly and write something like $q<0.05$ (FDR corrected), to distinguish it from uncorrected tests.

However, there are other procedures for controlling the FDR. [Storey's approach](https://web.archive.org/web/20200114021432/http://www.genomine.org:80/papers/directfdr.pdf) calculates $q$-values directly. These are intended to be like pFDR adjusted $p$-values, so you would reject null hypotheses associated with $q$-values below some threshold. In that case, you could easily write $q<0.05$.

Comment: Thanks! (1) "be willing to (?) an FDR-corrected null",  reject or accept? (2) "feel free to plug in a different 1−α, as necessary", why is it 1−α, not α?

Comment: Yes on both accounts. As to why, not enough coffee, I suppose :-)

Comment: For (1), the q-value of an individual hypothesis test is the minimum pFDR or minimum FDR at which the test may be called significant. So isn't it that the bigger the q-value is, the more likely the null is rejected?

Comment: I am still confused. is a test to reject its null on a sample, if and only if its q-value is no more than the FDR threshold? How do you explain if and explain only if?

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what "FDR corrected" mean and what "uncorrected" mean? What is corrected?

Comment: People sometimes refer to the results of the FDR procedure as "FDR correction", even though it's somewhat different from the Bonferroni or Sidak multiple comparisons corrections, which actually just apply a correction factor to the $p$-values. By uncorrected, I just meant tests where nothing has been done to compensate for the number of comparisons.